# Finding out the number of distribution of n marbles into k boxes with a condition

Tags: combinatorics

Recently I have faced a problem. The problem is here.
I have to distribute $n$ (distinguishable) marbles into $k$ boxes where each box should at least $x$ marbles. Two distribution are considered different if there is at least one marble which is contained by different boxes in the distributions.

For example,if $n=4,k=2,x=2$ the result will be $6$.

How can I find out the number of ways to distribute the $n$ marbles into $k$ boxes such that each box contains at least $x$ marbles.

I think  the concept of 'Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind' can help to solve the problem.But I'm not sure.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are the boxes distinguishable? I suppose so: in your example  the 6 options are 1,2|| 3,4;  1,3||2,4; 1,4 || 2,3 ; 2,3 || 1,4 ; 2,4||1,3; 3,4 || 1,2, where we enumerate box1 || box2 contents

Comment: yes,the boxes are also  distinguishable.